# Can't BER decode RSA public key with NDK Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, rsa, crypto++

I have problems using Crypto++ to save a RSA public key string. When decoding the key, I always get a BERDecodeErr exception.

Code:

```cxx
string RsaEncryptor::encryptor(string plaintext, string publicKey)
{
    std::string cipher;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    try
    {
        ByteQueue queue;
        Base64Decoder decoder(new Redirector(queue));
        decoder.Put((const byte *) publicKey.data(), publicKey.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();

        RSA::PublicKey rsaPublick;
        rsaPublick.BERDecodePublicKey(queue, false, (size_t) queue.MaxRetrievable());

        // BERDecodePrivateKey is a void function. Here's the only check
        // we have regarding the DER bytes consumed.
        CRYPTOPP_ASSERT(queue.IsEmpty());

        bool valid = rsaPublick.Validate(prng, 3);
        if (!valid)
            cipher = "RSA private key is not valid";

        RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(rsaPublick);
        StringSource ss(plaintext, true,
                     new PK_EncryptorFilter(prng, e,
                                            new StringSink(cipher)
                     ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
        ); // StringSource
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception &e) {
        cipher = e.what();
    }
    return cipher;
}
```

The public key is:

```
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDs648aASMAR9VprkzNVS7b‌​36N1hiYvbBG0c
dE0QkS3‌​H/sc3+Ej92lGBQErpBu9‌​LVhwN/beBX4QnbCn1eNS‌​rKoOzS4yqWlwOaCe0WLm‌​FDHCn1
cMTkX89cT4A0pc‌​jBbY+0W7htxWcqHxEQH9‌​x/AjQ9/4blerh1i6/lLI‌​o6hn2hB8kQIB
```

Comment: Please show a public or private key for test purposes. I suspect you need to use `Load` and `Save`, but I need to see a key to be sure. Also see [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/keys_and_formats) on the Crypto++ wiki. Also see [`ASN1CryptoMaterial<T>`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_a_s_n1_crypto_material.html) in the Crypto++ manual. `ASN1CryptoMaterial<T>` provides the `Load` and `Save`, and its the one that uses OIDs to describe the key (`subjectPublicKeyInfo` and private key). Finally, you may be interested in the [PEM Pack](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/pem_pack).

Comment: @jww This is Public key: MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDs648aASMAR9VprkzNVS7b36N1hiYvbBG0cdE0QkS3H/sc3+Ej92lGBQErpBu9LVhwN/beBX4QnbCn1eNSrKoOzS4yqWlwOaCe0WLmFDHCn1cMTkX89cT4A0pcjBbY+0W7htxWcqHxEQH9x/AjQ9/4blerh1i6/lLIo6hn2hB8kQIB

Comment: sorry to bother you, please take a look at my detailed description here:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/4ofdfSW9588]

Comment: By the way... When you get a well formed key, you should use `rsaPublick.Load`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDs648aASMAR9VprkzNVS7b‌​36N1hiYvbBG0c
> dE0QkS3‌​H/sc3+Ej92lGBQErpBu9‌​LVhwN/beBX4QnbCn1eNS‌​rKoOzS4yqWlwOaCe0WLm‌​FDHCn1
> cMTkX89cT4A0pc‌​jBbY+0W7htxWcqHxEQH9‌​x/AjQ9/4blerh1i6/lLI‌​o6hn2hB8kQIB
> ```

The key is malformed.

Stripping the Base64 encoding:

```cxx
FileSource fs1("key.b64", true, new Base64Decoder);
FileSink fs2("key.der");        
fs1.CopyTo(fs2);
```

And then viewing it under Gutmann's [`dumpasn1`](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/) reveals:

```
$ dumpasn1 key.der
  0 157: SEQUENCE {
  3  13:   SEQUENCE {
  5   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 16   0:     NULL
       :     }
 18 139:   BIT STRING, encapsulates {
 22 135:     SEQUENCE {
 25 129:       INTEGER
       :         00 EC EB 8F 1A 01 23 00 47 D5 69 AE 4C CD 55 2E
       :         DB DF A3 75 86 26 2F 6C 11 B4 71 D1 34 42 44 B7
       :         1F FB 1C DF E1 23 F7 69 46 05 01 2B A4 1B BD 2D
       :         58 70 37 F6 DE 05 7E 10 9D B0 A7 D5 E3 52 AC AA
       :         0E CD 2E 32 A9 69 70 39 A0 9E D1 62 E6 14 31 C2
       :         9F 57 0C 4E 45 FC F5 C4 F8 03 4A 5C 8C 16 D8 FB
       :         45 BB 86 DC 56 72 A1 F1 11 01 FD C7 F0 23 43 DF
       :         F8 6E 57 AB 87 58 BA FE 52 C8 A3 A8 67 DA 10 7C
       :         91
157   1:       INTEGER -1
       :         Error: Integer has a negative value.
       :       }
       :     }
       :   }
```

From above, the problem ASN.1 is at position 157. Looking at the file sizes:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jwalton  staff  261 Oct 18 23:09 key.b64
-rw-r--r--  1 jwalton  staff  159 Oct 18 23:18 key.der
```

It looks like there's two byte remaining to be processed. The `02` is the ASN.1 tag for an `INTEGER`. It should be followed by a length and a value, but there's only the length octet (`01`) is present. The value is missing.

```
$ xxd -g 1 key.der
0000000: 30 81 9d 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01  0..0...*.H......
0000010: 05 00 03 81 8b 00 30 81 87 02 81 81 00 ec eb 8f  ......0.........
0000020: 1a 01 23 00 47 d5 69 ae 4c cd 55 2e db df a3 75  ..#.G.i.L.U....u
0000030: 86 26 2f 6c 11 b4 71 d1 34 42 44 b7 1f fb 1c df  .&/l..q.4BD.....
0000040: e1 23 f7 69 46 05 01 2b a4 1b bd 2d 58 70 37 f6  .#.iF..+...-Xp7.
0000050: de 05 7e 10 9d b0 a7 d5 e3 52 ac aa 0e cd 2e 32  ..~......R.....2
0000060: a9 69 70 39 a0 9e d1 62 e6 14 31 c2 9f 57 0c 4e  .ip9...b..1..W.N
0000070: 45 fc f5 c4 f8 03 4a 5c 8c 16 d8 fb 45 bb 86 dc  E.....J\....E...
0000080: 56 72 a1 f1 11 01 fd c7 f0 23 43 df f8 6e 57 ab  Vr.......#C..nW.
0000090: 87 58 ba fe 52 c8 a3 a8 67 da 10 7c 91 02 01     .X..R...g..|...
```

Here's another view of the problem. `02` is the ASN.1 `INTEGER`, `01` is the length of the integer, but the value is missing:

```
0000090: 87 58 ba fe 52 c8 a3 a8 67 da 10 7c 91 ***02 01 ??***
```

---

Here's what a good 1024 bit key looks like. Its different than yours:

```
$ dumpasn1 key.der
  0 157: SEQUENCE {
  3  13:   SEQUENCE {
  5   9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
 16   0:     NULL
       :     }
 18 139:   BIT STRING, encapsulates {
 22 135:     SEQUENCE {
 25 129:       INTEGER
       :         00 D0 52 BA 4B 3F 44 AA 7B C9 C2 84 46 17 D6 17
       :         A0 43 03 69 7B 18 06 5B D4 EA 29 E2 74 24 40 62
       :         58 16 52 9D 73 82 77 D7 9D 13 97 53 71 76 9F B2
       :         99 CA 36 1E D4 E1 DF 0D BE C4 07 1E A0 F2 F2 E9
       :         EF 32 FA 00 4B 0B 8E C2 91 BA 8B 1D 1C 4D F0 98
       :         6C 64 C5 9E 4D EE 58 17 06 20 C9 3C 9A F0 33 BB
       :         A8 FC 7B 7B 6C F9 C6 FD A0 17 76 3A 3D 1D 7E E7
       :         42 C2 49 AD 4C 26 AE B6 F6 DC 99 A3 24 99 1A 30
       :         D9
157   1:       INTEGER 17
       :       }
       :     }
       :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

Notice there are two octets following the `02` (`01 11` below), and not one octet (like yours):

```
$ xxd -g 1 key.der
0000000: 30 81 9d 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01  0..0...*.H......
0000010: 05 00 03 81 8b 00 30 81 87 02 81 81 00 d0 52 ba  ......0.......R.
0000020: 4b 3f 44 aa 7b c9 c2 84 46 17 d6 17 a0 43 03 69  K?D.{...F....C.i
0000030: 7b 18 06 5b d4 ea 29 e2 74 24 40 62 58 16 52 9d  {..[..).t$@bX.R.
0000040: 73 82 77 d7 9d 13 97 53 71 76 9f b2 99 ca 36 1e  s.w....Sqv....6.
0000050: d4 e1 df 0d be c4 07 1e a0 f2 f2 e9 ef 32 fa 00  .............2..
0000060: 4b 0b 8e c2 91 ba 8b 1d 1c 4d f0 98 6c 64 c5 9e  K........M..ld..
0000070: 4d ee 58 17 06 20 c9 3c 9a f0 33 bb a8 fc 7b 7b  M.X.. .<..3...{{
0000080: 6c f9 c6 fd a0 17 76 3a 3d 1d 7e e7 42 c2 49 ad  l.....v:=.~.B.I.
0000090: 4c 26 ae b6 f6 dc 99 a3 24 99 1a 30 d9 02 01 11  L&......$..0....
```

Comment: Thanks @jww . C++ isn't really my area. please take a look at my detailed description here: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/4ofdfSW9588]]

Comment: can you give me a brief example of what should follows the tag, I don't quite understand whats the only one octet you point out

Comment: @HoàngHiệp - A well formed RSA public key was added. Its different than your public key, so don't paste it into your code and expect it to work. You might want to read the ITU's X.680, [Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680/en) and X.690, [ASN.1 encoding rules: Specification of Basic Encoding Rules (BER), Canonical Encoding Rules (CER) and Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690/en).